# How do I delete an embedded object in mongoid without persisting?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a question with many answers and for a specific request, I want to remove a few answers in-memory, but still not modify the database.

Is there a way to do this in mongoid?  Currently, I am doing something hideous like:

```
question = original_question.dup
question.id = original_question.id # Cause this is needed for the front end
question.answers.each do |answer|
  if foo
    answer.delete
  end
end
question
```

Answer (score 0):

`question.answers` is an `Array` so you can use the `Array#delete` method to remove specific items

```
questions.answers.dup.each do |answer|
  question.answers.delete(answer) if foo
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still deletes the answers from the document, for some crazy reason.  I dont want to persist the deletion, just want to update the question in memory.